# how to Find the end of the string while i know the start location of the string

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, uitextview

I am stuck with strange problem.In my UI-textview i detail text,I want to highlight/color the certain line or paragraph started with specific word.So far i was able to find the location of the starting word but not able to find the end of the line and paragraph.Problem is that the new line (\n) is not recognize as i had already tried.

Can any one help me how to find the solution.Here the code

```
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:self.textfiled.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, self.textfiled.text.length)];
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
            NSString *string =self.textfiled.text;
            NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
            unsigned long  lock=0;
            unsigned long i=0;
             [stirng replaceCharactersInRange:wordRange withString:@"\nདཔེར་ན། "];
            unsigned long length = [string length];
            unsigned long  paraStart = wordRange.length,paraEnd =0,contentsEnd =0;
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
            NSRange currentRange;

            for( i=0;![[self.textfiled.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(wordRange.location+i+1,1)] isEqualToString:@" "];i++)
            {

                NSLog(@"\n %lu------------>",i);
                lock=i;

              }


            NSLog(@"\n %lu------------>",lock);

          NSRange range = NSMakeRange(wordRange.location,wordRange.length);
           NSString *str = [self.textfiled.text substringWithRange:range];
             NSLog(@"\n%lu--------",[str length]);
            NSRange wordRanged1 = NSMakeRange(wordRange.location, 7+7);
            [stirng addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:22/255.0f green:123/225.0f blue:108/255.0f alpha:1.0f] range:wordRanged1];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you detect the point "."?

Comment: @Anhtu because it will appear several time

Answer (score 0):

Following the inspiration of your code, I created a similar solution that locates the **line end** and **paragraph end** given the starting character of a matched word. Paragraphs are separated by `\n\n` and lines are ended with `\n`. The end of your text field will likely need to be handled as a special case.

Note that the `.*` will match to the end of the line with the given regular expression options. The paragraph ends are located by finding a matching `\n\n`.

```
self.myText = @"hello world\n\nthis is a test\nsingle line\n\n";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"hello.*"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:self.myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, self.myText.length)];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

    NSRange lineRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"match start is %lu", lineRange.location);

    NSLog(@"line end is %lu", lineRange.location + lineRange.length);

    // Find paragraph ends:
    NSInteger i = lineRange.location;
    unichar lineSeparator = 0x2028;

    while (i < self.myText.length - 1) {
        // Case where string uses \n\n to denote a paragraph:
        NSString *subString = [self.myText substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        if ( [subString isEqualToString:@"\n\n"] ) {
            NSLog(@"found paragraph end at %ld", (long)i);
        }

        // Case where text view uses line separator characters:
        if ([subString characterAtIndex:0] == lineSeparator && [subString characterAtIndex:1] == lineSeparator) {
            NSLog(@"found paragraph end at %ld", (long)i);
        }

        i++;           
    }
}
```

In my sample, I get

```
match start is 0
line end is 11
found paragraph end at 11
found paragraph end at 39
```

I’ve created a little guide to visualize the results:

```
hello world++this is a test+single line++
01234567891111111111222222222233333333334
          0123456789012345678901234567890
```

This could be adapted to a standalone function that should provide the kind of results you are seeking.

Comment: "@Daniel" thanks for the answer ,i had been able to solve my 99% of the problem with this code but some time the string doesn't end with the specific word i had used, now I am trying to find a new  solution and i don't know what the new line character in iOS because both \n and \n\n doesn't working MY CODE---->for( i=0;(![[self.textfiled.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(wordRange.location+wordRange.length+i,6)] isEqualToString:@"ལྟ་བུ།"]  && i<[self.textfiled.text length]);i++)
  {NSLog(@"\n the location of the  space%lu----->",i);lock=i } i=0;  NSLog(@"\n hello %lu--->",lock);

Comment: @TenzinJinpa Just 1% to go then. Your text view may be using the line separator character that can be entered using control-return in Xcode. I've added a case in my answer to handle that character.